# matplotlib widget updates the wrong data

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I'm making a plot to compare band structure calculations from two different methods. This means plotting multiple lines for each set of data. I want to have a set of widgets that controls each set of data separately. The code below works if I only plot one set of data, but I can't get the widgets to work properly for two sets of data.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, TextBox

#cols = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'purple']
cols = ['#3f54bf','#c14142','#59bf3f','#b83fbf']

finam = ['wan_band.dat','wan_band.pwx.dat']
#finam = ['wan_band.dat'] # this works

lbot = len(finam)*0.09 + 0.06
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=lbot)
ax.margins(x=0) # lines go to the edge of the horizontal axes

def setlines(lines, txbx1, txbx2):
    ''' turn lines on/off based on text box values '''
    try:
        mn = int(txbx1) - 1
        mx = int(txbx2) - 1
        for ib in range(len(lines)): 
            if (ib<mn) or (ib>mx):
                lines[ib].set_visible(False)
            else :
                lines[ib].set_visible(True)

        plt.draw()
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Invalid range')
#end def setlines(cnt, lines, txbx1, txbx2):

def alphalines(lines, valin):
    ''' set lines' opacity '''
    maxval = int('ff',16)
    maxval = hex(int(valin*maxval))[2:]
    for ib in range(bcnt):
        lines[ib].set_color(cols[cnt]+maxval)
    plt.draw()
#end def alphalines(lines, valtxt):

lines  = [0]*len(finam) # 2d list to hold Line2Ds
txbox1 = [0]*len(finam) # list of Lo Band TextBoxes
txbox2 = [0]*len(finam) # lsit of Hi Band TextBoxes
alslid = [0]*len(finam) # list of Line Opacity Sliders

for cnt, fnam in enumerate(finam):

    ptcnt = 0 # point count
    fid   = open(fnam, 'r')
    fiit  = iter(fid)
    for line in fiit:
        if line.strip() == '' :
            break
        ptcnt += 1
    fid.close()

    bandat_raw = np.loadtxt(fnam)
    bcnt = int(np.round((bandat_raw.shape[0] / (ptcnt))))

    print(ptcnt)
    print(bcnt)

    # get views of the raw data that are easier to work with
    kbandat = bandat_raw[:ptcnt,0]                       # k point length along path
    ebandat = bandat_raw.reshape((bcnt,ptcnt,2))[:,:,1]  # band energy @ k-points

    lines[cnt] = [0]*bcnt # point this list element to another list
    for ib in range(bcnt):
        #l, = plt.plot(kbandat, ebandat[ib], c=cols[cnt],lw=1.0)
        l, = ax.plot(kbandat, ebandat[ib], c=cols[cnt],lw=1.0)
        lines[cnt][ib] = l

    y0 = 0.03 + 0.07*cnt
    bxht = 0.035
    axbox1 = plt.axes([0.03, y0, 0.08, bxht]) # x0, y0, width, height
    axbox2 = plt.axes([0.13, y0, 0.08, bxht])
    txbox1[cnt] = TextBox(axbox1, '', initial=str(1))
    txbox2[cnt] = TextBox(axbox2, '', initial=str(bcnt))
    txbox1[cnt].on_submit( lambda x: setlines(lines[cnt], x, txbox2[cnt].text) ) 
    txbox2[cnt].on_submit( lambda x: setlines(lines[cnt], txbox1[cnt].text, x) ) 

    axalpha = plt.axes([0.25, y0, 0.65, bxht])
    alslid[cnt] = Slider(axalpha, '', 0.1, 1.0, valinit=1.0)
    salpha = alslid[cnt]
    alslid[cnt].on_changed( lambda x: alphalines(lines[cnt], x) )

#end for cnt, fnam in enumerate(finam):

plt.text(0.01, 1.2, 'Lo Band', transform=axbox1.transAxes)
plt.text(0.01, 1.2, 'Hi Band', transform=axbox2.transAxes)
plt.text(0.01, 1.2, 'Line Opacity', transform=axalpha.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

All the widgets only control the last data set plotted instead of the individual data sets I tried to associate with each widget. Here is a sample output:
[image]

Here the bottom slider should be changing the blue lines' opacity, but instead it changes the red lines' opacity. Originally the variables `txbox1`, `txbox2`, and `alslid` were not lists. I changed them to lists though to ensure they weren't garbage collected but it didn't change anything.

Here is the test data [set1](https://pastebin.com/raw/N3hapQJg) and [set2](https://pastebin.com/raw/37Q4JPwT) I've been using. They should be saved as files 'wan_band.dat' and 'wan_band.pwx.dat' as per the hard coded list `finam` in the code.

Comment: If requested I can remove the TextBoxes to simplify it and just use the sliders to present the problem, which will shorten the code by ~24 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, using a `lambda` to partially execute some functions with an iterator value meant they were always being evaluated with the last value of the iterator. Switching to `functools.partial` fixed the issue.